# Hard "one-dimensional" cases of Fermat's Last Theorem

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Are there computable functions $p, q, r:\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}\to\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$ and an unbounded computable function $s:\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}\to \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 3}$ such that the statement

> For all $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$ we have $p(n)^{s(n)}+q(n)^{s(n)}\neq r(n)^{s(n)}$

is non-trivial but easier to prove than the full FLT?

Comment: It's a totally different equation. In particular there is just one unknown, so probably not that hard to solve for most choices of f, g and h.

Comment: Maybe you want p,q,r to depend on some other variable x instead of n? My apologies if I misunderstand your meaning, but to have them depend on n just seems a little off.

Comment: I want $p,q,r,s$ to depend on one variable.

Comment: In that case, in most cases I'd expect that the equation has a finite number of solutions over the reals, and that we can get good estimates on them with analytical means, so that excluding the existence of integer solutions will just be a finite check.

Comment: @einzwein I wouldn't.